# how remove marker from the map

Tags: android, google-maps

I create fragment with google map.
but when I want to delete marker from the map, I can not do this. I try everything and nothing help me. the marker relay delete but still shown on map what is the error in my code?

MapFragment.java

```
HashMap<String, BaseMarker> mAllMarkers = new HashMap<>();
private GoogleMap mMap;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
try {
        mRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, null);
    } catch (InflateException e) {

    /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
    }


    mMap = null;
    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();

  for (final BaseMarker entry : baseMarkers) {//list of markers
    Marker marker =  mMap.addMarker(markerFactory.getMeetingPointCreateMarker(getActivity(),  (MeetingPoint) entry));
                    marker.showInfoWindow();
                    entry.setMarker(marker);
                    mAllMarkers.put(entry.getMarkerId(), entry);
  }
  mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
         public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
           removeMarker();
          }
  });

    return mRoot;
}



public removeMarker(){//this call when I click in marker
 for (Map.Entry<String, BaseMarker> entry : mAllMarkers.entrySet()) {
        BaseMarker marker = entry.getValue();
        if (marker.getMarker() != null) { 
                marker.getMarker().remove();
                mAllMarkers.remove(marker.getMarkerId());

          }
    }

}
```

my mapFragment.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/mapFooter">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing all the markers right after you added them. You are doing this when the view isn't even completely loaded.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler way , just call `marker.remove()` like this:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        marker.remove();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Also concider calling `marker.setVisible(false)` instead to prevent it from re-appearing.